# Ubuntu won't boot (dual boot Windows/Ubuntu)

Tags: 11.10, boot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I fix grub so that it shows up during boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58034/how-do-i-fix-grub-so-that-it-shows-up-during-boot)

I recently installed Ubuntu alongside Windows, and the installation went fine, but when it said it had to restart to finish, I restarted it. When the computer turned back on, I wasn't prompted to start with Linux or Windows, it just went straight to Windows. How do I launch from Linux, or even given the option to launch Linux?

Comment: Alongside windows.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow recovery instructions: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute from Ubuntu or to start with the CD with boot-repair.  See here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair