# Windows wont boot in grub

Tags: 12.04

I have a dualboot with Windows xp and ubuntu. But when i try to select XP in the grub menu, it just blinks and returns to the grub menu. 
Any ideas?

Comment: Did it boot before? Did you change anything?

Answer (score 1):

First Boot into ubuntu and update the grub .

**sudo update-grub**

Then restart and loginto windows

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

found this link for you it might shed some light,(hopefully)

[How do I fix grub so that it shows up during boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58034/how-do-i-fix-grub-so-that-it-shows-up-during-boot)

Cheers!